# How to verify the local business by phone in google map ? I didn't see any field area to put my number?

Tags: google-maps, google-places, google-local-search, google-local-business

When I go to this link: https://support.google.com/business/answer/2911778, there is verification by phone option and I clicked on into your dashboard but in dashboard I could not find input field for phone number. How can I verify in this condition by phone?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Official [website](https://blupixel.co/) of Google My Business https://www.google.com/intl/en_pk/business/ and sign up and then it will gradually ask to verify your phone number via call or need email or postcard verification. As per Google latest Updates, you will get instant verification via phone most probably.

Hope this would help!!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to reproduce this issue.

According to the Google documentation on [Create and verify a local business on Google](https://support.google.com/business/answer/2911778), You can only verify your business through phone if you are verifying a business that is already on Google. If you want verify a new business on Google than you have to verify it by postcard that will reach your address with which you have registered your business in 1-2 weeks.

Hope this would help!!